# Where is the mistake in the following "proof" of Rokhlin Disintegration theorem?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm trying to better understand Rokhlin disintegration and what the conditional measures look like. I'm specifically thinking about the following formulation of the theorem.

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a measurable (in the sense of Rokhlin) partition, and let $X, \mathcal{F},\mu$ be a Lebesgue space. Then for almost all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ there exists a Lebesgue space $A, \mathcal{F}_A, \mu_A$ such that the following conditions are true: 
>  1) If $B \in \mathcal{F}$ then $B \cap A \in \mathcal{F}_A$ for almost all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ 
>  2) $\mu(B) = \int_X \mu_{A(x)}(B \cap A(x)) d \mu (x)$, and of course the function integrated is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable as a function of $X$. Here $A(x)$ denotes the element of the partition $\mathcal{A}$ containing $x$.

Now here is a sketch of how i think you could construct the measures $\mu_A$. Consider $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ to be the sub $\sigma$ field of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ which are unions of elements in $\mathcal{A}$. Then set $\mu_A (B) = \mathbb{E}(1_{B}|\tilde{\mathcal{A}}) (\omega)$, where the right hand side is taken at any point $\omega \in A$. I believe this makes sense since this conditional expectation should be constant on sets in $\mathcal{A}$. It is also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable by definition.

If this is how we define $\mu_A$ then we have:

$$
\int_X \mu_{A(x)}(B \cap A(x))d \mu(x) = \int_X \mathbb{E}(1_{B}|\tilde{\mathcal{A}}) d \mu (x) = \int_X 1_B d \mu (X) = \mu (B).
$$

Since $X$ is $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$-measurable and thus integrating $1_B$ and the conditional expectation should yield the same result.

I think $\mu_A$ are measures. Additivity should follow from conditional expectation properties, and they are defined on all measurable sets with values in $[0,1]$, and with $\mu_A (A) = 1$.

Clearly something is wrong with the above construction, as I don't believe i've used the assumption of $\mathcal{A}$ being a measurable partition, which is crucial. But I honestly don't see where it breaks down.

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ as you defined may not be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ at all ─ for instance, the partition of all points in $[0,1]$ is measurable (countably generated), so all subsets of $[0,1]$ would be $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$-measurable, while this is not true for Borel. So with this definition, $\mathbb{E}(1_B\mid \tilde{\mathcal{A}})$ would not even make sense.

This is not the main issue, however, because you can fix this; instead of taking the algebra of arbitrary unions of atoms, take $\mathcal{A}_1 \prec \mathcal{A}_2 \prec \cdots$ a chain of countable partitions such that $\bigvee_i \mathcal{A}_i = \mathcal{A}$ and set
$$\mathcal F=\sigma(\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,\dots)$$
the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains the entire chain. It's an exercise to show that the atoms of $\mathcal{F}$ are in bijection with the elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Now, suppose we were to define
$$\mu_P(E)=\mathbb{E}_\mu(1_E\mid \mathcal F)(w),$$
where we take any $w \in P$. Here is the second, more important issue: $\mathbb{E}_\mu(1_E\mid \mathcal F)$ is defined $\mu$-a.e. and every $P$ may have measure zero! You can see this in the same example of the partition made of all points of $[0,1]$. If you *fix* $E$, then the set of $P$s with at least one point where it's defined will have full measure. But it must work for *all* $E$, of which there are uncountably many. How can we do that? Here we use the separability/Borel assumption to fix a countable basis $\{U_i\}$ for the topology, so we can pick a full measure set $E$ such that $\mathbb{E}_\mu(1_{U_i}\mid \mathcal F)$ is defined for all $i$. But now there is the issue of extending the measure back to the whole space, which is not trivial.

At this point, we are essentially following the textbook proofs.